# What Latex template is this?

Tags: fonts, templates

can someone please tell me which latex template is used in this link below? I am guessing it is some standard template (anything which looks similar in terms of font and spacing is also fine).

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02719.pdf

Comment: https://arxiv.org/format/1804.02719 and click ‘Download source’.

Comment: As campa mentions, the source code is right there. Note you might want to add the suffix `.tar.gz` before opening it. I would assume that 7zip can handle it (or normal `tar zxvf` if you are on a system that has it).

Comment: @campa I didn't know Arxiv allows us to download the source, thanks!

Comment: @daleif Yeah, it worked after appending `.tar.gz`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nobody quite understands why arxiv never has extensions on their source downloads.